# Get file name and line number from Exception

Tags: c#, exception, .net-2.0, stack-trace, plugin-architecture

i have a c# windows application (developed in **Plugin Architecture**) , i want to log all unhandled exception from my application.
i am able to catch all the Exceptions.

i want to read the **File name and the line number from the Exception**. (in **.Net 2.0**)

i used

```
 if (exception.InnerException != null)
 {
     exception = exception.InnerException;
 }

StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(exception, true);
string fileName = trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
int lineNo = trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
```

its working fine with the exception in my application, if **any exception in the reference dll i didn't get the fileName and lineNumber**

Comment: I'm thinking something involving either logging every frame, or iterating through the frames until you find one that comes from your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is only available if the ".pdb" file for the DLL(s) in question is available.

Therefore, you should ensure that the appropriate ".pdb" files are alongside their corresponding DLLs.

You also need to enable full data in the PDB files. Debug builds do this by default, but release builds do not include the line number information.

You can configure a release build to do so by going to the project's Build page, ensure you have selected the "Release" configuration, then click the "Advanced" button at the bottom of the page. In the "Advanced Build Settings" dialog, you need to select "Full" for the "Debug Info" setting.

Comment: I think OP wants the file/line number of whatever inner-most call is within the application, NOT the file/line number inside the DLL

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Hmm, well I think it's because he doesn't have the "PDB" file with full debug info for what he's calling the "reference file".

Comment: Thnk u..i copied the .pdb file, now i got line number and file name.

Comment: @Matthew Watson If you do this for a release build, does this influence performance?

Comment: @KP_ No effect on runtime, it just makes the symbols and line numbers available. It probably will make the build very slightly slower.

Answer (score 0):

The first frame is not always the right answer. In my case, it was the last one. In general, I think it is the first one with a file.